# How can I rearrange df as the nodes index in pytorch geometric manner?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I'd like to rearrange my dataframe (data) as the node index to the original name in pytorch geometric manner for extracting node embedding.

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'Source': ['Rainfall', 'SP2', 'SP2', 'Inflow','Rainfall','Inflow', 'Inflow', 'Inflow','SWT','SP1','SP1','SWD'],
       'Target': ['SP1', 'Evp', 'Outflow', 'SP2','SWD','SWD', 'SP2','SP1','SP1','SP2','Evp','Loss']}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
nodes = pd.concat([df['Source'], df['Target']]).unique()
node_indices = {node: i for i, node in enumerate(nodes)}
df['Source'] = df['Source'].map(node_indices)
df['Target'] = df['Target'].map(node_indices)
```

This is my expected outputs

Expected outputs:
[image: Expected outputs]

Appreciate any though or suggestions.

Comment: post the code (expected output) and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: also, `concat` is for merging dataframes. since there is only one dataframe, this is not necessary...  maybe you want `groupby` or a different method ?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by _pytorch geometric manner_?

Comment: @D.L 
thanks for your response. Yeah, I tried, but it did not give me the expected output. The reason i used concat because this gives me unique number of each source and target. If you check on my df['Source'] and df['Target'], you will see each of them have a corresponding number and attribute (see node_indices). From that I hope to rearrange to get the same format as my expected outputs. I am not sure how to work and appreciate your though on this. Thanks

Comment: @Vitalizzare Sorry i might not use a right term in here. But the goal is to show interaction between source and target. if you look on my df and expected outputs, each node can be source and/ or target at the same time. For example, SP1 is a target, and it takes Rainfall and inflow as sources. On other hand, when SP1 is a source, it will have SWT, SP2 and Evp as the targets. There are some logics on my code, but i am not sure how to progress forward to achieve my expected outputs. Appreciate your though on that. Thanks

Comment: I can't see what kind of manual work have you done to get the expected outputs.

Comment: @Vitalizzare yeah, I am still in a learning progress with Python, and the code which I has uploaded does not give me what I want. I am struggling on the next steps. If you can give me a direction to progress forward, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the goal is to get an intermediate encoding of some parameters and make a visual representation of the relationships between source and target values (which seem to be all from the same pool, i.e. `nodes` in this case).

```py
data = {
    'Source': ['Rainfall', 'SP2', 'SP2', 'Inflow','Rainfall','Inflow', 'Inflow', 'Inflow','SWT','SP1','SP1','SWD'],
    'Target': ['SP1', 'Evp', 'Outflow', 'SP2','SWD','SWD', 'SP2','SP1','SP1','SP2','Evp','Loss']
}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# get all unique values of data
nodes = {name: code for code, name in enumerate({*df.values.flat})}

# replace values with their codes
df_coded = df.replace(nodes)

# connect original and encoded data in one DataFrame
# use multilevel headers to ease separate columns by names and codes
df_repr = pd.concat([df, df_coded], axis=1, keys=['Name','Code'])

# rearange columns like (source|name, source|code, target|code, target|name)
df_repr = df_repr.iloc[:, [0,2,3,1]]

# display transposed representation with hidden original indexes
print(df_repr.T.to_string(header=False))
```

With this we obtain the following output:

[image: encoded data representation]

**Update**

As of the line `df_repr = df_repr.iloc[:, [0,2,3,1]]`, this is reordering of columns by their indexes. Here `[0,2,3,1]` means *put the second column (which is indexed by 1) at the very end*. We can do it with `.loc` as well by passing names of columns in a desired order. It's just gonna be somewhat longer in this case:

```
df_repr = df_repr.loc[:, [('Name','Source'), 
                          ('Code','Source'), 
                          ('Code','Target'), 
                          ('Name','Target')]]
```

But if readability is a priority, then of course it's better to use `loc` instead of `iloc`.

*P.S. Because we are manipulating here only with columns, the following also works:*

```
reordered_columns = [
    ('Name','Source'), 
    ('Code','Source'), 
    ('Code','Target'), 
    ('Name','Target')
]
df_repr = df_repr[reordered_columns]
```

Comment: @Vializzare Many Thanks. This is what I am looking for. Just one question, hope you dont mind I am asking. My first question is that this code " df_repr = df_repr.iloc[:, [0,2,3,1]]" what does number 0, 2, 3 ,1 mean?

Comment: @PonlokPeter It's rearanging of columns, see the **Update** in the answer for detailes.